# how can I remove zeros from exponent notation

Tags: c#, number-formatting, format-specifiers

I'm using exponential formatting to format a decimal number in C#. 
For example if the number is

```
0.0001234567
```

Formatting with

```
(0.0000123456).ToString("E4");
```

Shows

```
1.2345E-004
```

How can I remove leading zero from exponent so it read as below?

```
1.2345E-4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you need to always show 4 digits after decimal point, try

```
"0.0000E+0"
```

so it will show

```
(0.0000123456).ToString("0.0000E+0"); //1.2345E-5 
(0.0000120000).ToString("0.#E+0");    //1.2000E-5
```

if you don't need to show 4 digits after decimal points use

```
"0.#E+0"
```

so it will show

```
(0.0000123456).ToString("0.#E+0"); //1.2E-5
(0.0000120000).ToString("0.#E+0"); //1.2E-5
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct, I need one digit before and 4 digits after decimal point.

Answer (score 12):

Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#EFormatString):

> The case of the format specifier indicates whether to prefix the exponent with an "E" or an "e". The exponent always consists of a plus or minus sign and a minimum of three digits. The exponent is padded with zeros to meet this minimum, if required.

This is with the standard number specifier.

However, with the [custom number format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), you can set the number of 0's:

```
987654 ("#0.0e0") -> 98.8e4
```

For your case, it's

```
(0.0000123456).ToString("#0.0E0"); //12.3E-6
```

*Edit after BobSort comment*

If you need scientific notation, you can specify that you need only one digit before decimal with the following:

```
(0.0000123456).ToString("0.00#E0"); //1.23E-5
```

Comment: your answer is close enough, the only problem is scientific notion need only one digit before decimal point. I guess I need to remove # from start of format string