# Remove leading zeros from exponent when converting ToString

Tags: c#, decimal, tostring, number-formatting, exponent

Let's say I have a double n = 0.00000123456

In one case I may want to show 1 decimal place 
   n.ToString("E1") => "1.2E-006"

In another case I may want to show 4 decimal places
   n.ToString("E4") => "1.2346E-006"

But I don't want the leading zeros on the exponents, these numbers are for an axis where there is limited space.

I would like to see "1.2E-6" and "1.2346E-6" : nice - no leading zeros!

I read [how can I remove zeros from exponent notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784842/how-can-i-remove-zeros-from-exponent-notation) and I see I can use n.ToString("0.0E+0") and n.ToString("0.0000E+0") respectively.

That's great, but, given that I have an integer variable *requiredDecimalPlaces*  telling me the number of decimal places I require at any time, would I have to create this format string with a loop, adding zeros each time?! That seems hacky. If this is the way to do it could somebody let me know? But like I said, converting my variable requiredDecimalPlaces (value 4 let's say) to a string "0.0000" and then appending "E+0" to the end in order to create "0.0000E+0" seems over-complicated.

Comment: `new string('0', 4)` would create a string with four zeros if you want to avoid a loop.

Comment: That's true, thanks juharr. Though ideally I'd still like a solution that doesn't require me to be building a format string separately.

Comment: What's wrong with
`n.ToString("0." + new string('0', numberDecimalPlaces) + "E+0")` ?

Comment: @juharr Thanks for the answer, I went for this implementation in the end, just as Heinz did too. Please make your comment into an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a standard numeric format that will do that so you'll have to create a custom one.  And the easiest way to create that format would be the following.

```
number.ToString("0." + new string('0', decimalPlaces) + "E+0");
```

Comment: Thanks @juharr that's exactly what I needed.